# jQTouch execute code when AJAX page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, web-applications, jqtouch

When the content is static:

```
<a href="#nearme">Click</a>
<script>$('#nearme').bind('pageAnimationEnd', function(event, info){});</script>
```

When the content is AJAX:

```
<a href="page.html">Click</a>
```

How do I bind something to occur after the AJAX (page.html) is loaded?

Comment: your question is not clear. please try to clarify so you could get an answer. a href="page.html" is not an ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

This question pertains to jqtouch which makes AJAX requests from regular anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [demo](http://jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home), in particular the "GET Example" under AJAX section. Essentially, you want to have the anchor element to link to a page which returns a "jQTouch page", i.e. `<div id="pageID">...</div>`.

So, in your case, you may have this anchor:

```
<a href="page.html" class="slide">Click</a>
```

And the `page.html` may be something like:

```
<div id="ajaxPage">
  <div class="toolbar"><h1>Title</h1></div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```