# How to load dynamic pages with JQTouch

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, jqtouch

I am trying to build a web app with JQTouch. I actually have it all working nicely if I hard code all the content in. However, the site needs to be entirely dynamic.

Before a user logs in, there is to be only one page visible - a login page. Once logged in, the app downloads content that that particular user is allowed to see. For example, user 1 may be able to see a home page with 3 links on, each link pointing to a page containing 3 more links. user 2 may only see 2 links on the home page, but the first pointing to a page that contains two more links, and the second pointing to a page that contains 5 more links. The number of pages is dynamic, and different for every user. Because of this, I cannot create div's to load content into.

How can I set up this in JQTouch. I want each page to load on demand. I don't need the code to achieve this, just the theory behind it. For example, do I create a "template" div, and clone it each time a new page is to be loaded, or do I run a script to work out how many divs I will need, and then create them all?

Any advice would be greatly welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to load your pages via AJAX. You can see this in their demo. Just go to AJAX > GET Example.

Take a look at the answer I posted on another question: [jQTouch execute code when AJAX page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603236/jqtouch-execute-code-when-ajax-page-is-loaded/3673504#3673504)

If you want to put the logic in the front-end, you could simply use the `pageAnimationEnd` callback function documented here: http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/CallbackEvents.

Comment: Thanks.  The question was more about how to handle the containing divs, than how to load the content via ajax.  For example, if a link on the home page has an href that links to "#anotherPage", I would need to create a div with an id of "anotherPage" to load my content into.  As this is a dynamic site, I am unable to hard code the required containing divs.  so my question is about how to create those divs.  Do I just create one div and load all of my content into that, do I create each div at run time each time it is required etc.

Comment: I'd say you want to dynamically manipulate the tabs, as the jQuery UI Tabs allows you to do that. Take a look at the "Simple manipulation" of the tabs demo pages: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation